# A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

hi i am trying to run `JAX-RS Web Service` project which contain sample hello world web service, but publishing it in the `Tomcat Server 7.0` shows following errors.

Below are stacks-trace from the console in eclipse.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.<clinit>(ServiceFinder.java:165)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory.getAllServletContainerProviders(ServletContainerProviderFactory.java:66)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:132)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 11 more

Dec 27, 2013 2:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Dec 27, 2013 2:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

Please anyone help me to find out what is problem ?

Comment: You can also add the apache commons libraries http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you are using Jersey 2, you can download Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle from their site and add JARs from **ALL** subfolders (api, ext and lib) to the WEB-INF/lib folder of your project.
In my case, adding guava-14.0.1.jar fixed that particular ClassNotFoundException, but started failing on another unresolved reference, so I just dropped everything in my lib folder and managed to start the server without any problems.

Comment: hi , thnks anyway i got answer i need use particular set of jar files, that i got from jesrey site. it is running well.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is the root cause:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
```

... so it looks like you're probably missing a dependency jar file (Guava, by the looks of it) from the classpath of the relevant classloader. If you're following a "hello world" tutorial, double check any steps which specify where to put jar files.

Comment: hi thnks for replying immediately. i checked all jar files are correct placed . i followed the link http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html, and mainly Tom Cat server is too not starting. showing error: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may missing some dependency Jar file in your project or in your container.
Jar file may be one of the below.

```
google-collections-***.jar  
google-collect-snapshot-***.jar
google-collections-1.0-***.jar
```

Comment: hi i am using Jersey based JAX-Rs web Service and all Jar files i have copied to projects.

Comment: is there any another project running on same server ?

Comment: Other Dynamic Web projects are running well in Tom Cat Server

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy and save your project to other location and delete from the eclipse. later delete the Tomcat from eclipse and make sure all the entries of your project gets removed from the  Tomcat directory(server.xml file) and from your deploy path: wtpwebapps (in mine case).

Once done with clean up and integrate Tomcat with eclipse again, and start the Tomcat.

Bingo!!! it works.